# Two Android applications with the same user ID

Tags: android

From  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html:

> It's possible to arrange for two applications to share the same Linux
>   user ID, in which case they are able to access each other's files. To
>   conserve system resources, applications with the same user ID can also
>   arrange to run in the same Linux process and share the same VM (the
>   applications must also be signed with the same certificate).

How can we achieve same user ID for two applications? Any example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [`sharedUserId`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) and [`sharedUserLabel`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uidlabel) in the AndroidManifest.xml file to the same value. As an example, if I have the following 2 manifest files (I only included the beginning):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package1" 
      android:sharedUserId="userId"
      android:sharedUserLabel="@string/label_shared_user" 
      android:versionCode="1" 
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
```

and

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package2" 
      android:sharedUserId="userId"
      android:sharedUserLabel="@string/label_shared_user" 
      android:versionCode="1" 
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
```

then they will both share the same user.

Comment: However I strongly discourage doing this.  The vast majority of apps shouldn't do it; it is only for special cases.  Using this results in a lot of subtle differences in behavior (such as all of the apps sharing the same permissions) that most developers shouldn't be inflicting upon themselves.

Comment: That is great !!! but also is there a way to get applications having same shareUserId from a third application. I mean i wish to detect the 2 applications having same sharedUserId

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html: the uid will be the same for both applications.

Comment: an important addition is that you can only install two applications with the same shareduserid is both the applications were signed with the same certificate

Comment: @hackbod *"it is only for special cases"* Can you give some examples?