# Issue retrieving Shared preference values

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

We are saving the following from one application:

```
final CheckBoxPreference mCheckPref = new CheckBoxPreference(sContext);
mCheckPref.setKey("alertnotification");
```

and we are retrieving it from a second application follows:

```
mContext = context.createPackageContext("com.android.abc",Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE |     Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
boolean alertnotification = prefs.getBoolean("alertnotification",true);
```

I always get the alertnotification as false, even during the first time where I have set the default value to be true. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

"Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later."

Comment: is there any workaround for this, like using shareduserId between these apps as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354035/two-android-applications-with-same-user-id)