# How to call B_app by A_app on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have write 2 app, A_app and B_app.
In A_app, I want to call B_app and launch B_app's CalledActivity.
But the B_app's MAINActivity is MainActiity not CalledActivity.
In A_app, I try below code to call B_app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.bapp","com.example.bapp.BActivity"));
intent.putExtra ("test2abc", "abctest2");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in B_app's BActivity has code in onCreate as below:

```
Bundle params = getIntent().getExtras();
if (params != null) {
    String temp = params.getString ("test2abc");
    Toast.makeText (BActivity.this, temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But there are some error as below:

```
01-10 10:47:16.904: E/AndroidRuntime(8355): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.example.bapp/.BActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{418a3788 8355:com.dlink.nas/u0a7} (pid=8355, uid=10007) not exported from uid 10115
```

I want the B_app is only called directly by A_app without other call it.
How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to the "B_app" Android Manifest under `BActivity`'s `<activity>` node:

```
 android:exported="true"
```

So it looks something like:

```
<activity android:name=".Bactivity" 
  android:label="@string/b_activity"
  android:exported="true">
<!--rest of activity node -->
</activity>
```

Another way to "export" is by setting an intent-filter (also in manifest):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="myFilter" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Since Android does not allow access to all Activities by default, just the main one.

To answer your edited question, there **is** a way to allow apps to call each other's components without exporting, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354073) SO answer. You have to add the `sharedUserLabel` and `sharedUserId` attributes in the manifest. However, they note that it is not recommended, since it can cause slight changes in operation.