# Android - Create modules for my app

Tags: android

I have my application. It's working well.
Now I developed a small addon which installs to system with hidden from launcher icon:

```
<activity android:name="GitHubSearch"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'm trying to launch this Activity using this answer:
[Android: Starting An Activity For A Different Third Party App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518407/android-starting-an-activity-for-a-different-third-party-app), but my app fails with Exception - Activity not found.

```
final Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.me.module","com.example.me.module.MyActivity"));
            startActivity(i);
```

I checked 10 times the package names and activity names, that I'm passing to intent. Everything is fine.

Where is I'am going wrong?

Comment: Please post the code where you are trying to launch the other activity.

Comment: So you want to call `GitHubSearch`? It seems you are trying to launch `MyActivity` instead.

Comment: If you want to start the GitHubSearch activity, why do you write MyActivity in the code for `setComponent`?

Comment: I provided here sample component name and activity name to hide my company. In the code the Activity name is correct. By the way, code working fine if I change in manifest category from default to launcher...

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:exported = "true"` to the xml for your Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all you needed was

```
android:exported = "true"
```

To the `activity` node in your manifest xml.

By default, Android does not export Activities. Exporting an Activity means that it allows anything to start the Activity.

There are two ways to export - the above way, and setting a custom `intent-filter`.

If you want your new module to only communicate with your app, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354035/two-android-applications-with-same-user-id/6354073#6354073) SO answer, however they note it is not recommended.